# Cuts through image by screen resolution

Tags: c#, wpf, image, grid, screen-resolution

I'm encoutering a wierd issue.
I'm applying an image to a grid, and it cuts through the image by screen reolution, and not logiclly.
At 1280 x 800 it shows like this:
[image: link to image]

and when it's 800 x 600 it shows like this:
[image: link to image]

Which is kinda messed up because with lower height resolution, it shows more of the picture.
Any idea why the hell that's happening?
this is my code :

```
Grid MyGrid = new Grid();
Image img = new Image();

StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel();
myStackPanel.CanVerticallyScroll = true;

Image myImage = new Image();
BitmapImage myImageSource = new BitmapImage();
myImageSource.BeginInit();
myImageSource.UriSource = new Uri("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Desert.jpg");
myImageSource.EndInit();
myImage.Source = myImageSource;
// myImage.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
// myImage.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
// myStackPanel.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
// myStackPanel.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;

myStackPanel.Children.Add(myImage);

MyGrid.Children.Add(myStackPanel);

_LayoutRoot.Children.Add(MyGrid);
```

Comment: How exactly do you want to show the image?

Comment: Is this just an aspect ratio thing? The horizontal looks the same; the vertical looks different - but: the aspects ad the two resolutions are not the same

Comment: to fill screen... but not cut through the image i need it all

Comment: Sorry for being witless, but i don't understand what that means. how can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem:

```
myStackPanel.Children.Add(myImage);
```

Don't use a [`StackPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel.aspx) if you want the image resized properly (why is there a StackPanel anyway if it contains nothing else?), here it will just overflow and cut. There are various other [panels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx), e.g. `Grids`, which are better suited for this.

Comment: What is my alternative? i'm new to C#. when i tried directly applying it to the grid it didn't fill the entire screen.

Comment: @eric.itzhak: If you just add the image to a grid it should stretch by default. Also **you should throw out all that C# and use XAML**.

Comment: ya but before this image there is a 3d Animation created in the XAML. should i create the grid in the xaml and hide it untill that code point? and when i edit it to the grid it dosen't strech.

Comment: @eric.itzhak: That probably would be a better idea, but i don't know your complete situation, maybe [navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx) might also be an option.

Comment: for some reason the grid with image in it dosen't fill the entire screen it's acting as if centered

Comment: @eric.itzhak: Did you resolve it? (As you accepted my answer)

Comment: Yes i did. just set the image to Fill it's container and it solved it. Thank you!

Comment: @eric.itzhak: Glad to hear that it worked out, you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The program does exactly what you tell it to. You're using `StackPanel`, which means all items in it will be “stacked”. By default, the orientation of the `StackPanel` is vertical, which means the second control is placed below the first one, the third below the second etc. And all of them use all of the width available to them.

In your case, it means the image is stretched to the width of the window. If its height doesn't fit, the bottom will be cut off. Alternatively, if the height of the window was too big, you would see empty space below the image.

The easiest way to see this is to not have the window maximized and try changing the size of the window.

If you don't want this behavior, you can use different panels, like `Grid`, as H.B. suggested.

Comment: Thank you. for some reason when i add Grid with image in it it dosen't fill entire screen